# regex in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, regex

One of the column in my table have data like this

```
@Stream<TTL>@Topic<Abstimmung_Carbon_Accounting>@Date<03-May-2012<@Time<BN,APH>@Participants<MUELLER,RECHTE>@Pages<2>
@Stream<m20>@Topic<Shared_Space_Afternoon>@Date<12.10.12>@Time<Call>@Participants<dehaan>@Pages<2>
```

What I want is to select the `Topic` part only, using mysql query. Regex for this is something like `Topic\<\w+\>`

But how to use it to select part from a field in mysql.

Output needed:

`Abstimmung_Carbon_Accounting`

`Shared_Space_Afternoon`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: MySQL regexes can match only. You can't capture/extract from a string with them. That will have to be done in client-side code.

Comment: If you need to extract data from a column, it will perhaps be useful to add more columns to your table or rethink the structure of your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem without using regex

Assume you have a table `table2` with one column `col1` of `varchar` type and it contain following values

```
@Stream<TTL>@Topic<Abstimmung_Carbon_Accounting>@Date<03-May-2012<@Time<BN,APH>@Participants<MUELLER,RECHTE>@Pages<2>
@Stream<m20>@Topic<Shared_Space_Afternoon>@Date<12.10.12>@Time<Call>@Participants<dehaan>@Pages<2>
```

Then you can use following query to get your required output

```
select substring(col1,Locate('Topic<',col1)+6,(Locate('>',substring(col1,Locate('Topic<',col1)+6))-1)) as result  from table2 
where substring(col1,Locate('Topic<',col1))!=""
```